# Only one object with custom constructor logic gets fully initialized in a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to map one object onto another one (`Record` -> `ParsedAddress`) with the following code:

```java
public class ParsedAddress extends Address {

    private static final Map<Field, Consumer<String>> MAPPINGS = new EnumMap<>(Field.class);


    public ParsedAddress(final Record record, final List<Field> order) {
        super();

        this.mapFields(record, order);
    }

    private void mapFields(final Record record, final List<Field> order) {
        this.setupMapping();

        for (final Map.Entry<Field, Consumer<String>> mapping : MAPPINGS.entrySet()) {
            final Field field = mapping.getKey();
            final String value = record.getField(field, order);
            final Consumer<String> setter = mapping.getValue();

            setter.accept(value);
        }
    }

    private void setupMapping() {
        if (!MAPPINGS.isEmpty()) return;

        MAPPINGS.put(SALUTATION, this::setSalutation);
        MAPPINGS.put(FIRST_NAME, this::setFirstName);
        MAPPINGS.put(SURNAME, this::setSurname);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

(`Address` is a data object that contains all the mapped fields.)

I call the constructor like this:

```java
records.stream()
       .map(record -> new ParsedAddress(record, ORDER))
       .collect(toUnmodifiableList());
```

But only the first "record" gets mapped. The result collection contains one `ParsedAddress` that has all the data (so the logic works alright) and `ParsedAddress`es that have `null` fields.

I debugged it and managed to narrow the issue down to the `setter.accept(value)` line. It works exactly the same whether the constructor is called inside a stream or a loop.

Is it something about the object initialization? But then, why is exactly one object mapped successfully and the rest is not?

*EDIT*:
The `Record` class only contains the data to be mapped. Here's the `getField` method:

```java
public String getField(final Field field, final List<Field> order) {
    final int index = order.indexOf(field);

    return index == -1 ? null : this.data.get(index);
}
```

Comment: What is `Record` class? What does `record.getField()` do? Maybe it removes the field from list as "a bonus"?

Comment: @Amongalen, no it does not modify the data. I've updated the question with a snippet. `ORDER` is the exact same static instance for the whole batch of objects so it's not the issue of `getField` returning `null` on the condition.

Comment: What's the type of `records`?

Comment: @Taschi, you mean the to-be-mapped data in `Record`? All of them are simple strings and they are held in a `java.util.List`.

Comment: "It works exactly the same whether the constructor is called inside a stream or a loop." - What do you mean by that? It is supposed to be that way, no? There is nothing that looks incorrect in your code. It needs debugging - put a breakpoint on `setter.accept(value);` and check all variables. We can't really help you much more than that based on the code you provided.

Comment: @Cube, no. I mean, what is the type of the field called `records`, which you call `stream()` on.

Comment: @Taschi, it's a list of `Record` instances.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `MAPPINGS` map is a lazy-loaded static map yet the `this` keyword is not.

This results in a map that is filled-in exactly once but with references to public setters of the very first object that reached it (the one that lazy-loaded the map).

So every consumer in `MAPPINGS` is a public setter for the very same object (the one that lazy-loaded the map).

That was fun!

Comment: Could you share how you worked around it? By making it non-static or something else?

Comment: @Amongalen, I turned `MAPPINGS` into an instance variable. Since it needs to hold a reference to the current object anyway, I reckoned it would have a small impact on memory since `EnumMap`s are based on an array anyway. I can imagine that a different option could be to turn the method references into lambdas that would get `this` as an argument but I can't see any benefits of that since there would have to be (`MAPPINGS.size()` * number-of-`Record`s) instances of `Consumer`s created anyway (returned from said lambdas).